# Free interactive software for vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, math-software

I'm looking for a free, interactive program that allows me to graphically draw vectors, and at the same time display specified dot products, magnitudes, etc. as I move/resize the vectors. It can be either web-based or otherwise, doesn't really matter, but must have the above capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [GeoGebra](http://geogebraweb.appspot.com). I'm not sure if this does everything you want it to but it definitely can let you draw and resize vectors, as well as do calculations with them.

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/